# How can I solve a second order ODE in python when state vector is made of vectors?

Tags: python, vector, simulink, ode, odeint

I'm trying to "translate" a Simulink model (built to solve a second order ODE and shown in the picture below) into python.

[image]

inW and inT are vectors of dimensions [1601x2], gains MFW and MFT have dimension [2x1] and gains MC and MK have dimension [2x2]. All initial conditions have been set to 0.

out_acc, out_rate and out_disp all have dimension of [1601x2].

Any help in setting up this problem in python?

Thank you!

\Simone.

Comment: Are inW and inT really 1601x2, or are they 1x2 defined at 1601 time points?  As for setting it up in Python, the specifics of that will depend on which ode solver package you are using.

Comment: They are indeed 1x2 defined at 1601 time points!

Comment: As a solver package, I'm  trying to use scipy.integrate.odeint but to be honest I don't really know if that is adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a for loop that updates the initial condition at each time step!